# Wordpress ping spam issue with Ping services?

Tags: plugins

My client wants me to install a plugin from here: http://www.maxblogpress.com/plugins/mpo/ that optimizes how WP pings. If you read the article, the version he mentioned were 2.1 and 2.3, if I am not wrong. Does this issue still exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stay away from this particular plugin, as far as I remember this developer requires registration and forces email subscription on you.

As for issue itself - does your client has particular issue to worry about pings at all?

Comment: To get banned from Ping services? I don't know of any issue myself, maybe my client is just being precautious.

Comment: Quoted from my client's message: "I would say that we are concened about over pinging, and are trying to make our site an authority site and don't want to get de-listed right off the intial luanch due to over pinging."

Comment: @Joann I am not aware of any information that excessive pinging can get you de-listed (or listed either) anywhere. It is merely mechanism to ease propagation of content (with questionable effectiveness), it doesn't affect authority of ones content.